# numpy slicing that would always return an array

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Given a `numpy` array and a `__getitem__`-type index, is there an idiomatic way to get the corresponding slice of the array, **that would always return an array and never a scalar**?

Examples of valid indices include: an `int`, a `slice`, an ellipsis or a tuple of the above.

Say I have an array like this:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

I am looking for an operation that would be equivalent to `a[whatever]` in all cases except when `a[whatever]` returns a scalar (for example, `a[1,1]`). In those cases I'd like this alternative operation to return a single-element array instead.

Comment: It might be worth clarifying that you want a 1D vector returned in place of a scalar, which I think is implied.  (since a single-element array can have any number of dimensions).  I have, in the past required that any slice of a 2D table *always* return a 2D table, in which case I used `numpy.atleast_2d` inside a `table` class that I wrote myself that mirrored many of `array` methods.  It would probably break all kinds of stuff if you were able to get `atleast_*D` behavior out of a numpy array.

Comment: One possible use I can think of is when you always want the result to be a view, so that modifying it changes the original. If that is what is desired, `atleast_Nd` isn't good enough - probably need to convert the `int` indices to `slice`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to return a single-element array in cases where a scalar would otherwise be returned, why not just use `numpy.atleast_1d` on the result of the slice?

E.g.:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
print x[0,0]
print np.atleast_1d(x[0,0])
print np.atleast_1d(x[:,:3])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a neat way to preserve the type of the array (I am using a subclass of `ndarray` and would like the result to be of the same type as `x`).

Comment: I should also note that I don't always know the type of `x` *a priori*.

Comment: @aix - Unfortunately, there's no `np.asanyarray` equivalent for `np.atleast_1d`, as far as I know.  @Sven's answer below is probably your best bet if you need to always preserve the type of the array. As it will always return a slice, the type should be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly more complex version that always returns a view into the original array (of course provided that you don't do any advanced indexing; this should be guaranteed by your specification of valid indices):

```
def get(a, item):
    if not isinstance(item, tuple):
        item = (item,)
    if len(item) == a.ndim and all(isinstance(x, int) for x in item):
        return a[item + (None,)]
    else:
        return a[item]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `np.array(a[whatever])`? Don't think there is a simpler/more idiomatic way than this.

Comment: Actually that doesn't do what the OP wants (e.g. have a look at the shape of the resulting array when the result of the slice is a scalar.)